# Probability of a dot to appear in a sphere

Tags: math, geometry, probability

**Entry:**

- a 3D-graph of `m` vertex
- a sphere of radius `r`, volume `V`, any center
- a vertex `v` of the graph

**Question:**

What is the probability of `v` to be inside the sphere?

**Possible answer:**

The intuition tell me this probability is: `1 / (m * V)` but I can't prove it.

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://math.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: Sorry for my mis-understanding of Stackoverflow rules. Since this problem comes with a programming project, I supposed this was the right place. It received an answer, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your equation looks wrong to me as `m` does not affect probability. The distribution of vertex coordinates does. If it is **uniform** in some volume `V0` covering the whole sphere volume `V` then the probability should be:

```
p = V/V0
```

if you want to have actual count of such points then:

```
n = m*p = m*V/V0
```

I can not provide you with mathematical proof but you can simply do this programaticaly. For example let `V0` be axis aligned cube with half size `R=1000.0` and center `(0,0,0)` with the sphere as its biggest inscribed sphere with `r=1000` and the same center so:

```cpp
float x,y,x0,y0,z0,r;
float rr ,X0,Y0,Z0,R;
int i,m,n;

r=1000.0; x0=0.0; y0=0.0; z0=0.0;  // sphere V
R=1000.0; X0=0.0; Y0=0.0; Z0=0.0;  // cube V0
m=10000; // number of points
Randomize();
for (i=0,n=0;i<m;i++)
 {
 // random uniformly distributed position inside V0
 x=X0+2.0*Random()*-0.5)*R;
 y=Y0+2.0*Random()*-0.5)*R;
 z=Z0+2.0*Random()*-0.5)*R;
 // compute sphere radius^2
 rr = (x-x0)*(x-x0)+(y-y0)*(y-y0)+(z-z0)*(z-z0);
 // if inside
 if (rr<=r*r) n++;
 }
// here n should be close to m*V/V0 = (4.0/3.0)*M_PI*r*r*r/(8.0*R*R*R);
// the bigger the m the more closer it should be.
```

This approach is sometimes used to compute the `Pi` number.